# Next.JS - NODE_ENV !== "production"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

I have NODE_ENV='development' set in .env

```
function nodeEnv() {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
        console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV) <= Logs 'development'
        return oneThing
    }
    return otherThing
}
```

If I set NODE_ENV='production' the function still returns oneThing

At no point does the function return otherThing

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you saying that if you set NODE_ENV to `production` it still doesn't return `otherThing`?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Updated for clarity. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, so what does it print then after you set NODE_ENV to `production`?  That's probably what you need to solve this.  I must say at this point, however, that you would probably be better off with a more robust configuration package.  Go for [wj-config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wj-config).  Does everything dotenv does + everything config does, plus some more.

Comment: When I change NODE_ENV='production' it still logs 'development'. You're absolutely correct not robust at all. I will give wj-config that a try. Thank you.

Comment: Since it is still showing `development`, it probably means that you have a .env file somewhere that is more specific, like .env.local that is overwritting your configuration.  But yes, give **wj-config** a try.  I made it, so comment here if you need help.  I tend to over-explain stuff.  My quickstart section is not so quick. :-(

Comment: Awesome thank you. The only file is .env. When I restart the dev server it logs that it has loaded the environment variables. Not much I can do about that one!

Comment: the code is on the server side or client side?

Comment: If I console.log() or display process.env.NODE_ENV in the browser, I always get 'development'.

Comment: Internally, Next.js always sets `NODE_ENV` to `"development"` when running the app in dev mode (likewise for production mode and `"production"` value). Use a different, custom environment variable if you want to set/use it in your code (e.g. `APP_ENV`).

Comment: I figured that out in the end. Thank you.